# Why border of <th> and <thead> both not showing here?

Tags: css

Why both border not showing?

http://jsfiddle.net/r8mA7/

```
<table>
<thead style="border-top:10px solid red; background:yellow">
    <tr><th style="border-top:10px solid green">Name</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Bob</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tom</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Some HTML and CSS would help, maybe you have a cascade issue.

Comment: Um, it looks fine in Firefox.  What browser are you using?  http://i42.tinypic.com/2ahrvhz.png

Comment: @MiffTheFox - sorry it was for <th>

Comment: IT works. http://jsfiddle.net/GHBe7/

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks - now green border not showing. I want to show both

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's the expected behaviour. Odd, but expected.
**The borders are collapsing**, and the thicker one prevails.

You can see it with this example: the touching borders on first row collapse, the ones on the second row don't.
On the first row the first cell gets the thicker border (10px green > 5px red), and the second cell gets the thicker border (5px red > 3px green).
On the second row there are no "adjoining" borders to collapse, so the 10px green and 3px green borders show up normally.

```
<table>
<thead style="border-top:5px solid red; background:yellow">
  <tr>
    <th style="border-top:10px solid green">Name</th>
    <th style="border-top:3px solid green">Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="border-top:10px solid green">Name</th>
    <th style="border-top:3px solid green">Name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Need me to clear up the explanation anyhow?

PS: theoretically you could use the [border-collapse](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/border-collapse/) property on the table to prevent that, but I'm not managing.
Also, the default value seems to be not to collapse.

Further reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#borders

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<thead>` element as the selector like this:

```
thead { background: red; }
```

[You can see an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/uwQFW/)

Comment: i'm giving `thead { border-top:10px solid red}` but not working

Comment: @metal - for that, `table { border-collapse: separate; }`, but only one border will win here :)

Comment: `border-top:10px solid red` works fine for me. Please check, that your browser actually uses the css style and accepts the `border-top` property.

Comment: @Nick - oh i wasn't aware . ok but how show both borders? is there any way?

Comment: @metal - If it's at the top, give the border to the table itself?, aside from that I'm not sure of a way, but don't rule it out...I've never come across this situation, could be a new trick I'm just unaware of.

Answer (score -6):

Give a class name to your table. And style it as below

```
<style>
.mytable thead{
//your style goes here
}


</style>
```

EDIT:

```
<table>
<thead style="border-top:10px solid red; background:yellow">
    <tr><th style="border-left:10px solid green">Name</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Bob</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tom</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Try this code. The border of thead and th are being shown. May be th has a greater precedence when there is a same style attribute conflict between th and thead