# CSS why doesn't this work?

Tags: css

its not showing the right border

```
<th style="border-style:solid; border-right:1px; border-left:0px; border-bottom:0px; border-top:0px;">s
  </th>
```

Comment: Don't you normally put CSS in the header? Just saying... I know this is valid, but it's so.... dirty...

Comment: Your markup is wrong. You can't have data directly inside a th tag. You should put it inside a td.

Comment: duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788824/why-border-of-th-and-thead-both-not-showing-here

Comment: @Adarsh R: How is that wrong? A th can contain most of the things that td can contain.

Comment: @BoltClock - A TH should contain TDs which inturn should hold the data. Data should never be placed directly inside a TH.

Comment: @Adarsh R: I think you're confusing th with tr. A th is a table header cell. While it certainly isn't supposed to contain tabular data, it can still contain any text.

Comment: You're right! My bad :( Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try

```
<th style="border-right:solid 1px gray"></th>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give border-color as well.

Comment: What colour is your page? Hope it is not white too.

Answer (score 0):

in you css

```
th.giveaclassname {border:0 1px 0 0 solid black;}
```

in your html

```
<th class="giveaclassname">..</th>
```

or it might be that the borders are collapsing, and the thicker one prevails (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788824/why-border-of-th-and-thead-both-not-showing-here))